# Hubot: Is it possible to mention everyone in a xmpp chatroom?

Tags: hubot

Dear stackoverflowsians,

our Hubot has a XMPP adapter and sits in a XMPP chatroom.
Is it possible to fetch a list of all the other users in the chatroom to let hubot mention them?
For example:

```
me: hubot ping everyone
hubot: johndoe , joe , bob , alice ping
```

if the users johndoe,joe,bob and alice are in the chat.